# How can I program a keyboard shortcut to select top 1000* from selected table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut in ssms 2012 that when pressed will have the same effect as `select top 1000 * from mytable` ?

I have explored this already: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174178.

Often times when exploring a database very frequently the programmer needs to select top records from tables.

If this is not customizable in ssms, I would be happy with a c# solution,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tools -> Options, then Environment -> Keyboard -> Query Shortcuts. Assign a key to be:

```
select top 1000 * from
```

Notice no table name. Now press OK, and open a new query window. Highlight a table name and then hit your key combo.

Comment: You need to highlight a table name in your query window. Works like a charm! Also, normally changes to SQL Server settings don't impact any current open query windows, so close them all and re-open.

Comment: thanks so much! im unable to get it to work yet, but im sure i will since you say it does

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'from'.

Comment: oh i seem this works if you highlight the text as opposed to highlight the object in the left

Comment: I have tried this and working fine but actually what i need is when i press my customized keyboard shortcut lets say ex: ctrl+3 i want select * from text should be pasted on query window

Comment: @Pradeep did you figure it out, cowboy?