# shortcut for fetching data from the object explorer tab in sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

It's annoying to do two clicks every time I want to fetch some data. is there a shortcut?

This is not the same as [How can I program a keyboard shortcut to select top 1000* from selected table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900981/how-can-i-program-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-select-top-1000-from-selected-table)

I DO NOT WANT TO WRITE A TABLENAME IN A NEW QUERY, I want to select a table in object explorer and then doing a key combo to fetch me the query I want.

It's like how the delete button works but I want another keystroke that will give me the data.

BEFORE CONSIDERING THIS A DUPLICATE: Maybe read better before duplicating this question as this is clearly not the same as the other one. Do not just read titles but read contexts.

Comment: How is this different from the duplicate that you say isn't a duplicate? This seems like a lot more effort than it is worth. Typing select top 1000 * from SomeTable is barely more than a second. Finding my mouse, opening object explorer, finding the table in the list takes a way more time than just typing the select statement.

Comment: @SeanLange First-world problems. Time is money.

Comment: If you want to delete a table, you go to object explorer and then hit the delete button on your keyboard. I'm asking if there is a shortcut for selecting top 1000 * from some table on the object explorer tab. The reason why this is different is that the other post suggest that you need to write the table name in a new query which I do not want.

Comment: @MoDGenesis Yes, the shortcut is LITERALLY CLICKING YOUR MOUSE 2 TIMES

Comment: And I would like a keyboard shortcut... two times is too much if you have to keep clicking 10 different tables every time.

Comment: Don't accept substitutes. Buckle down and learn how to write an SSMS extension, then add this thing to the context menu. Sell the extension for big bucks.

Comment: If your keyboard has a context menu key (mine does not), the shortcut is Context Menu Key followed by "w". You still have to press these in sequence rather than simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you I found a fast alternative thanks to you. But how did you know it was "w" on your keyboard?

Comment: @MoDGenesis So you swapped a mouse click for a keyboard click. This should be a case study in efficiency.

Comment: I did *something* that caused the keyboard accelerators to display, and saw it was "w". Unfortunately I don't seem to able to reproduce this now (Alt simply closes the menu). So... yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the object explorer tab: Hit right click on the table and then press 'w' on your keyboard.

When you are searching for a database through your keyboard, hit context menu on your key then press 'w'.

Special thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert

Comment: How / Why is that easier than right click and left click?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to totally stay away from the object explorer, make a proc that selects top 1000 and bind it to a shortcut.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_selecttop1000
@tablename SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @query = N'SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM ' + @tablename
END
GO
```

Now go to Tools, Options, Keyboard(expand this), Query Shortcuts. Now pick an unused binding, add sp_selecttop1000 to it, restart SSMS.

Now you can highlight a table in the query window, and use the keyboard shortcut to select top 1000 from the highlighted table.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the query window while still selecting "selecttop1000" from object explorer

Comment: And all you have to do is add this to the `master` database of every server you ever work on... which is a bit of a drawback.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm humoring OP since this request is ridiculous anyway. The amount of time OP spent so far on this post vs the amount of times it takes to click the mouse 2 times will even out in maybe 5 years of fulltime SQL dev work in SSMS.

Comment: There are degrees of ridiculousness that need to be respected, and we ought to draw the line at modifying the system databases. Whatever absurdity you undertake in your client to scratch a personal itch can always be justified, with enough determination. :-) I don't dispute the answer is at least valid...