# Issues trying to get keyboard command to work in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, hotkeys

I read [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900981/how-can-i-program-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-select-top-1000-from-selected-table) that you can put `select top 1000 * from` in tools > options > keyboard > query shortcuts and it should be able to pull the top 1000 of a dbo you've highlighted. This doesn't seem to work for me. When hitting the bound hotkey, in my case ctrl+3, while highlighting a dbo in my query, nothing happens.

I'm using SSMS 17.9.1 via royal TSX (RDC connection).

Any thoughts that could be preventing this from working for me?

*EDIT: I went to Keyboardchecker.com to make sure that ctrl+3 was registering correctly, so it's not an RDC issue, best I can tell.*

Comment: Sounds like you want more of a snippet if you're looking to have literal text added to your SSMS query window. Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/add-transact-sql-snippets?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I'm not looking to add text to an existing query. I'm looking for a way to highlight the text of a dbo in my query, for example, `dbo.Employees`, hit a hotkey, and have it run the query `select top 1000 * from dbo.employees`.

The link I referenced explains how to do that, it just doesn't work for me. Where it was 7 years old, I didn't want to resurrect it.

Comment: In that case, I read in one of the comments that the table name itself needs to be selected as if you were going to rename it. That just seems dangerous to me, lol. And far from helpful.

Comment: I figured it out. I just needed to close that save the query, close it, and open it back up. Must have been an SSMS error? Not too sure, but it works now!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just needed to save the query, close it, and open it back up. Must have been an SSMS error? Not too sure, but it works now!